# Replace Loading gif with text when download is finish (cURL)

Tags: php, curl, replace, download

i am using CURL to download few files, my code looks like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Sometimes files are pretty big so it take some time until download finish, so i want to display a loading gif  (something as this: http://4gettv.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Loading_video.gif) But i have no idea how to know that download is over, can somebody help me with this code?

p.s. Everything is doing on the server , so not dowloading on my PC :)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Loading indicators are client side features. A server doesn't need one. If you're trying to download a file on server side, you can try loading it in the background, and have a GUI page (displaying the loading icon) that polls the server for completion of the copy. When it's done, redirect to another URL.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believed that:

```
...
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
// here download is done
```

If not, you might use the callback option of curl:

```
function progressFunction($clientp, $dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow) {
    if ($dlnow == $dltotal) {
        // finished
    }
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, '0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progressFunction');
```